# Could a medieval society expand a river

Tags: science-based, medieval, engineering

What are the ways a society with  medieval or at most middle age technology go about widening and deepening a river?

Comment: Did you ask [google first](https://www.google.com/search?q=river+dredging+history)?

Comment: "Winding"? What do you want to do to the poor river? Anyway, the answer is shovels. Lots of shovels. See the [Naviglio Grande](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naviglio_Grande) for a 50 km long canal dug in the 12th and 13th centuries (1179 to 1258, 90 years of digging).

Comment: Yes I did ask Google it provided little information all I found out is the process is called dredging not how medieval civilizations would have accomplished this

Comment: Shovels were invented before the middle ages.

Comment: I meant widening I'll edit it

Comment: Please note that you cannot simply make a river wider and deeper. It is a complicated engineering problem. The big issue is that the amount of water which is in the river is what it is, and to make the river wider and deeper *and keep it filled with water* you need to either bring extra water from somewhere, or else canalize the river so that the flow of water is restricted between dams. Both solutions require careful planning and involve spending a lot of sweat and treasure to put them into practice.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this question doesn't give details on any of the surrounding circumstances, and kind of implies a lack of research on the topic. Just "googling it" is the minimal effort level of research. I recommend looking up modern methods and possibly researching how the same tasks were accomplished in medieval times.

Comment: @AlexP Would most likely be weirs in this instance, possibly just one if the section they want to widen and deepen had a small enough elevation change over the run. Course this does not work for one of the most common reasons to want to do this namely increasing the maximum draft/beam supported by the navigation channel in that case you need locks instead and how you would go about building functional lock gates at that scale with medieval tech is another problem, maybe power them using water wheels or something? IDK

Comment: @MttJocy: Locks were known since the 10th century in China, and since the late 14th century in Europe; they became widespread towards the end of the Middle Ages / early Renaissance, when Milan engaged in a massive [canal building project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naviglio_di_Bereguardo). Until the 20th century, locks were almost always manually operated; you don't *have to* power them with anything more than muscle power -- they are operable by unassisted humans.

Comment: @AlexP Except we were talking about boats with a beam and draft so large even a river needed to artificially be widened and deepened so you are likely talking about ship locks there is a reason the gates on those things weigh in at hundreds of tons each, they need to be that strong.

Comment: @MttJocy: The gates are *balanced* on their hinges. For real, lock gates were operated manually until well into modern times.

Comment: @AlexP Canals were also generally small until modern times that said to be fair gates 10's of meters wide and similar in depth that were strong enough to handle even a small difference in water height over a channel that wide were not really possible until a cheap means to produce steel at an industrial scale became a thing either. Granted they could probably have built a canal like Suez much earlier if someone was willing to pay for it as it is all on the same elevation so doesn't have that problem but making locks bigger than a few meters in width or depth I suspect would be.

Answer (score 5):

- Canals have been dug in the classic era. Dig a big canal parallel to the river, then dam the river to redirect it onto the new, deeper bed.
- Some [dredging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dredging#History) happened in Roman times, too.
- Dam the river, remove major obstacles as the water falls, then re-open the dam.

Answer (score 0):

A technology that could change terrain didn't change until the industrial revolution. Everything had to be done by hand.
People would usually dig out a canal and then built a dam. The water was forced to flow away.
Then they could widen it, make it deeper, lay down stones on the bottom and sides to prevent it from changing course. (Which happens often with uncontrolled rivers) etc.

Comment: Wrong.  See e.g. the Chinese Grand Canal, build starting ~500 BCE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Canal_(China)